# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in your code on line 9

Tags: php

```
<?php

$name          = $_POST['name'];
$price         = $_POST['price'];
$absolute_path = "/Plants/List/index.html";

$PlantFile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "$absolute_path", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$trimmedname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
fwrite($PlantFile, "\n\n<div class='wrapper one $trimmedname' id='main'>\n<h1>$name</h1>\n<p>Price: $price</p>\n <?php if($_SESSION[id]) {?> \n<button>Delete $name</button>\n<script> var simple = \"<?php echo $trimmedname; ?>\"; $(\"button\").click(function(){$(simple).remove();}); </script> \n <?php } ?> \n</div>\n");

fclose($PlantFile);


?>
```

I keep getting the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in your code on line 9

Could anyone help? Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you trying to write php scripts into a file? Either way you need to review your concatenation and use of `<?php` in the `fwrite()` line.

Comment: Yes its going into a new file.

Comment: So you are writing the `<?php ` into a new file, so that new file will be dynamic right?

Comment: Yes, basically im trying to add a part where if someone is logged in they can hit a delete button to remove some code. But if you aren't logged in you can't see that code.

Comment: Remove code right out of the file or from the browser page? I don't know your application, but it sounds like you might be going down the wrong road with removing code write from the file itself.

Comment: Well im removing a div using the .remove() method on Javascript

Comment: Ok, then you don't want to rewrite the contents of a file directly. You want to just add that text block using a conditional, not with any `fwrite()` functions. You want to manipulate the view, not the core php file at the file level.

Comment: Well i had it working ealier but when i added the delete method it stopped working. Like someone posts something, then i add it to the file.

Comment: Yeah, you really don't want to mess with the core `.php` file unless you really have a good reason. If you are trying to manipulate the user experience, you just have your `if` / `else` do that work to add and remove content, including javascript blocks.

Comment: This script looks like you should be using a database but maybe aren't?

Comment: No, i figured it out. I appreciate the help man! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your use of the curly braces in combination with the `$` sign aka `{$(simple).remove();}`.

try replacing `$` with `\$` so that your `jQuery` `$` sign wont be treated as a php variable.

Comment: I tired that but it didn't work. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Oops. I lied lol it worked. Thanks very much!

Comment: Questions that are about basic PHP syntax errors should not be answered. They should be closed as a duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071) only.  See: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232). Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution anyway.

Comment: I usually don't have problems with this but I looked at other questions of the such and I didn't find it 100% helpful. Plus either way it doesn't hurt to have someone else take a look at your code and give some tips. But thanks for the hint! Have a good one :D !